# Coloring strands in braids

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data, knots

Is there an option, or simple work-around, for coloring each strand in a three-dimensional `BraidImage` differently?  For instance, I'd like to render a braid image such as

```
KnotData[{4, 1}, "BraidImage"]
```

in red, green and blue.

Comment: it's a hack, but `i = 1;
KnotData[{4, 1}, "BraidImage"] /. 
  {y_GraphicsComplex} :> {{Red, Green, Blue}[[i++]], y}`

Comment: @JasonB. Great solution!

Comment: Jason:  Indeed, perfectly acceptable solution (+1).  You can post it as a full solution and if I don't receive a superior solution in a day or so, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dunno if it's any better than @Jason B.'s answer, but I think `"BraidImageData"` gives you the graphics objects used in the image, which you can play around with as so, for example:

```
knotdata = KnotData[{4, 1}, "BraidImageData"];
colors = {Red, Blue, Green};

Graphics3D[
 Transpose@{colors, knotdata},
 Boxed -> False,
 ViewPoint -> Front
 ]
```

[image: BraidImage]

Comment: Anne:  Excellent.  Thanks (+1).  I'll wait a day or two to accept either this, Jason's or (possibly) someone else's.

Comment: Great! This is the right way to do it, my solution was just a hack.